# Error converting data type varchar to float even though the variable/column is already a float datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm operating in SQL Server 2012 (v11). I am aware that many others have asked questions surrounding this issue, but none were particularly helpful to my own predicament. I additionally have two issues that I'm trying to over come and help with either is much appreciated.

For some context, I'm currently trying to (Goal 1) transpose a Table that contains three separate unique IDs and some survey data which was collected over a period of 5 years. Currently, the table is structured so that one record equates to a single survey's data in any of the 5 years. However, I want to transpose the data so that one record equates to the entirety of an individual's survey data. I'm attempting to accomplish this goal by using a Crosstab, which I have successfully accomplished in the past.

However, my (goal 2) current issue is that I keep receiving the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 89
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

What is tripping me up is that in my code below, EntityID on line 89, but it is a numeric number and already stored in SQL as a float datatype. So why would I be getting this error message?

Here is my code for reference, very open to any suggestions that would also accomplish goal 1 in a better way.

```
SELECT EntityID
  , insig_id
  , UserID
  , Cohort
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '1' THEN pam_score  ELSE NULL END) AS MY1_PAM_SCR
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '1' THEN pam_lvl  ELSE NULL END) AS MY1_PAM_LVL
  , MAX(CASE WHEN MY = '1' THEN srvy_date ElSE NULL END) AS MY1_SVY_DAT
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '2' THEN pam_score  ELSE NULL END) AS MY2_PAM_SCR
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '2' THEN pam_lvl  ELSE NULL END) AS MY2_PAM_LVL
  , MAX(CASE WHEN MY = '2' THEN srvy_date ElSE NULL END) AS MY2_SVY_DAT
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '3' THEN pam_score  ELSE NULL END) AS MY3_PAM_SCR
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '3' THEN pam_lvl  ELSE NULL END) AS MY3_PAM_LVL
  , MAX(CASE WHEN MY = '3' THEN srvy_date ElSE NULL END) AS MY3_SVY_DAT
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '4' THEN pam_score  ELSE NULL END) AS MY4_PAM_SCR
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '4' THEN pam_lvl  ELSE NULL END) AS MY4_PAM_LVL
  , MAX(CASE WHEN MY = '4' THEN srvy_date ElSE NULL END) AS MY4_SVY_DAT
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '5' THEN pam_score  ELSE NULL END) AS MY5_PAM_SCR
  , SUM(CASE WHEN MY = '5' THEN pam_lvl  ELSE NULL END) AS MY5_PAM_LVL
  , MAX(CASE WHEN MY = '5' THEN srvy_date ElSE NULL END) AS MY5_SVY_DAT
  into #svy_onerow
FROM #svy_counter2
    GROUP BY EntityID, UserID, insig_id, Cohort
    ORDER by insig_id
```

Thanks in advance, for any help you great people can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the type for column `MY`? You are checking it as a `char`. Do you not want something like `SUM(CASE WHEN MY = 1 THEN...`?

Comment: It is an int. I've solved the issue though, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There error message of line 89 is saying that is the code block, not necessarily line 89. 
Since you have several functions referencing 3 fields in your #svy_counter2 you need to confirm that pam_score, pam_lvl, and srvy_date are valid datatypes for those functions. I've seen dates being stored in varchar fields ('20190101') and if you try to take the max of that that you won't get what you're after unless you explicitly cast it to a date, datetime datatype.

try something like this: 

    `select distinct cast(pam_score as float) from #svy_counter2
    select distinct cast(pam_lvl as float) from #svy_counter2
    select distinct cast(srvy_date as datetime) from #svy_counter2`
 
see if one of them errors for you. That will tell you that field is the problem.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification about the error message, I'm currently learning SQL so this is helpful.

I've figured it out based on your advice to go through and ensure all variables are the correct datatype.